# What reliable HDD to buy for private data archive, 1.5 - 2TB

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage

I need to buy a new HDD for my private data storage (photographs I take mostly)
Please recommend me what brand / model is less likely to fail/break.
I don't care for performance, I care for **reliability**

I've got several HDDs in recent yeards, mostly Seagate and one Samsung, and all of them had serious problems.
The current one I was using (1.5TB Seagate) is dying (makes clicking sound when running and became very slow) so I need to make a backup ASAP.

Comment: I like Western Digital's stuff, but that's my personal opinion and isn't based in facts or evidence

Comment: [HGST](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-benchmark-stats-2016/)

Comment: Before we can recommend a specific model, we need a bit more info: a) Do you have a hard price limit? Do you want an internal or an external drive? Do you care about size as long as it's >=2TB? Do you have any other special wishes (like 2.5" vs 3.5")?

Comment: Reliability test for hard drives: https://github.com/linuxhw/SMART/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Honestly,  I would recommend an SSD.
A samsung 840/850 or whatever.
You can get them in 2tb size, they are currently a bit expensive, but very reliable.

They have no moving parts to fail.  No heads, motors, or platters because of this they can even handle significant drops with no effect.

They have significantly more spare sectors, and way better error management than hard drives.

Beyond that they are screaming fast, and use much less power.

[image: ssd]

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16820147371

Operating Temperature
    0°C ~ +70°C

Operating Humidity
    5% to 95%, non-condensing

Comment: Also bonus: SSDs only "age" when you write and not so much when you read as opposed to HDDs which "age" on both kinds of access.